# How do I include files in Git but not in Github with PyCharm?

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have created a Django project in PyCharm Professional, which I imported into version control Git. I have imported the project as a whole.

Now I want to create a Github repository but there are files and folders that I want to be on Git locally but not on the Github repository.

I can share my project on Github through the VCS menu, but it will include everything.

Is there a way to have files and folders in Git but not in Github ? Maybe add them later ?

Comment: Well, don't push the changes you make. Keep them locally. Possibly in a separate branch. Nothing will be stored in the remote github repo unless you explicitly push them.

Comment: When I "Share Project On Github" from the VCS menu, everything that is in the Git is pushed. I can not choose which folders are pushed. I can add folders and files in the Ignored list but this is for Git.

Comment: Well, don't do that. Create a github project, set it as the remote for your own, local, git project, and push the commits you want to push, and don't push the commits you don't want to push. You won't go anywhere without clearly understanding how git works. Fortunately, there are seeral freely available git books online.

Comment: To what end do you want this separation? Is it because you want a clean working tree and some files not on GitHub? Because then ignoring them with `.gitignore` might be an option for you, other wise you could have an extra branch as @JBNizet said. You would then want one or more branches for your local repository where you have those local files plus the commits for that you push to GitHub. (Or you start with a complicated `git stach` ecosystem).